# InvocationTargetException in Easy mock of JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am facing an issue while running `JUnit` using `EasyMock`. Please find below the source files - `UserTest.java` (JUnit file) and `UserFinder.java` (Application file to be unit tested).

**UserTest.java**

```
Class UserTest
{
  ...
  @Test
  public void testFindUserFunction() throws Exception {


    DAO daoMock = EasyMock.createMock(DAO.class);       
    User user = new User("john", "stephen", "city street", "bangalore");
    EasyMock.expect(daoMock.userExists(user).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.replay(daoMock);       
    String userFirstName = user.getFirstName();
    User resultUser = UserFinder.findUser(userFirstName, daoMock);      
    PowerMock.verify(daoMock);      
    Assert.assertEquals(user, resultUser);
  }
}
```

**UserFinder.java**

```
Class UserFinder {
...
...
public User findUser(String userFirstName, DAO dao)
{
return dao.findUser(userFirstName);
}
...
...
}
```

In JUnit, I have created a mock object `daoMock` and added below `expect` behavior.

```
EasyMock.expect(daoMock.userExists(user).andReturn(true);
```

In the below line of **UserFinder.java**, I need to pass `daoMock` as the class is already existing and designed in that way. When the below line is executed through JUnit, I am getting `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

```
User resultUser = UserFinder.findUser(userFirstName, daoMock);
```

I am new to `EasyMock` and I thought setting `expect` adds to the behavior of the `daoMock` object but it is not. Please help me about how to call `dao.findUser` line as I cannot mock this line since it is in application file. How can I mock and run the JUnit for this case in `EasyMock`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mock the method

```
EasyMock.expect(dao.findUser(userFirstName).andReturn(user);
```

instead of

```
EasyMock.expect(daoMock.userExists(user)).andReturn(true);
```